# SSRS report total fields

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, ssrs-2012

How to show the total of each page in SSRS report. What I exactly mean is if pageNumber = 1 total should be sum of amount on page 1, if pageNumber = 2 total should be sum of amount of page 2 + total from page 1, etc...

Comment: do you need carried forward as well?

Comment: No, I don't need carried forward

Answer (score 1):

.Have you tried using the running value function?

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159136.aspx

You can also use ReportItems![CellName] to enable you to display the value in the report footer if required.

If this does not give what you require and you have a fixed page size eg A4 you can calculate the page totals and Page Numbers as a fields in your data set. This is more powerfull in settings where for example you want to print a set of customer statements in a single print run. Each customer statement would need its own page numbers and totals. Again you can use ReportItems to display these values in the relevant part of the report as they would appear at the detail level of the dataset. In this case you add a hidden field(s) containing the values you require on the detail line and pick them up using ReportItems. You can also force a page break at the end of each Page number group

To repeat the report Header / Footer on each page see this link
http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/repeat-table-header-on-each-page-in-ssrs/.
To start with go to the footer properties and make sure repeat on first and last page is checked.

Comment: I added textbox1 on report body and add expression: =RunningValue(Fields!LineAmount.Value, sum, "SalesInvoiceDS")
I also added textBox2 in footer and add: ReportItems!Textbox1.Value
but both fields are shown only on last page

Comment: Please see revised answer